# How to move to the next 100 copies repositories?

Tags: c#, octokit.net

octokit.net
  I search for repositories with the following code

```
public async Task<int> SearchReposit(string searchQuery_str, string lang_str)
{
            // Поиск по "Реозитариям"            
            request_repo = new SearchRepositoriesRequest(searchQuery_str); // mvc client side framework - Структура клиентской стороны mvc           

            switch (lang_str)
            {
                case "C#":
                    request_repo.Language = Language.CSharp;
                    break;

                case "All":
                    request_repo.Language = null;
                    break;
            }

            // Коллекция репозитариев 
            resultRepo = await client_cur.Search.SearchRepo(request_repo);

            // Количество репозитариев
            int countRepo_dec = Convert.ToInt32(resultRepo.TotalCount);

            return countRepo_dec;
}


public method_1
{
 for (int i = start; i < fin; i++)
{
                    // Обращаемся к экземпляру репозитария
                    var instanceRepo = resultRepo.Items[i];


                   //....
 }
}
```

Number of search results ~> 100,000
In the search result, I only get 1-100 copies.
How to go to the next 101 - 200 copies?

[image]

Comment: My guess would be that it’s a paginated response.

Comment: @favoretti What should I do with this problem?
I seem to have found a similar problem, but I cannot understand how to use it for my own task.https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/issues/1453 . Sorry, I don't know much about programming. Could you describe the solution in more detail?

Comment: Sorry man, have no Windows handy. Normally it means that you get a pagination cursor with the response and can fetch the rest of the results per page.